# How can i check current user is administer in civicrm hook?

Tags: hooks, civicrm-home

I am using the hook_civicrm_tabset for rename the tab name. Tab rename code is working properly. But i want to add condition if user is admin then rename the tab name. How can i check user is admin in hook_civicrm_tabset hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like `CRM_Core_Permission::check('administer CiviCRM')` which returns true or false depending on if they have that permission.